# Area under the Kaplan-Meier curve for a time interval

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'd like to compute the area under the  Kaplan-Meier curve for a interval time. I know I can compute the area under the curve from 0 to t, aka the restricted mean survival time with the `print.survfit` function:

```
library(survival)
km <- survfit(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ 1, data = ovarian)
print(km, rmean = 600)
```

But, what I'd like is the area under the Kaplan-Meier curve for a time interval, e.g. from t1 to t2.
Is there a way to left truncate the computations of the area under the Kaplan Meier curve ? 
Any suggestion will be welcomed !

Comment: I have little experience with survival analysis but it seems to me that if you can compute `0 - t1` and `0 - t2` it would be quite simple getting `t2 - t1`

Comment: Thanks. That's  right. But actually, I'd like also to have the variance of this quantity. `print.survift` gives se(rmean) but because the rmean between 0 - t1 and 0 - t2 are not independant, it is not straightforward to have the variance of the area under the curve between t1 and t2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I eventually figured out how to compute the variance of the AUC between t1 and t2 thanks to the `surv2sample` of the `surv2sampleComp` package. It does so by resampling.

```
library("survival")
library("surv2sampleComp")
data(veteran)
# we need a group variable to use the surv2sample function
veteran$group <- as.numeric(veteran$karno < 70) 
rmst <- surv2sample(veteran$time, veteran$status, veteran$group, npert = 500, tau_start= 100, tau = 200)
rmst$group0
#---------------
                             Est.       Lower 95%   Upper 95%          SE
RMST                       43.4025761  32.1207404  55.8039197  6.15988181
# results truncated
```

Answer (score 1):

The variance "around" a survival curve is very much like the variance of a proportion from a binomial process. In your case you apparently are able to calculate a variance for the data up to t1. So truncate the data at t1 and then calculate a variance to t2.

Like @Oka I wondered why you would want the AUC, but then I realized that AUC is just "life expectancy" for a complete KM curve and the units would be "years" or some other time unit.

```
 str(ovarian)
'data.frame':   26 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ futime  : num  59 115 156 421 431 448 464 475 477 563 ...
 $ fustat  : num  1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 ...
 $ age     : num  72.3 74.5 66.5 53.4 50.3 ...
 $ resid.ds: num  2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ rx      : num  1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ ecog.ps : num  1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 t1 = 400;  t2 = 700

 km <- survfit(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ 1, data = ovarian)
 print(km, rmean = 400)
 #---------------
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ 1, data = ovarian)

         n     events     *rmean *se(rmean)     median    0.95LCL    0.95UCL 
      26.0       12.0      355.6       18.5      638.0      464.0         NA 
    * restricted mean with upper limit =  400 


 km2 <- survfit(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ 1, 
                 data = ovarian[ !(ovarian$futime <=400), ])
 print(km2, rmean = 700)
#-----------------
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ 1, data = ovarian)

         n     events     *rmean *se(rmean)     median    0.95LCL    0.95UCL 
      26.0       12.0      532.2       41.1      638.0      464.0         NA 
    * restricted mean with upper limit =  700
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I think your suggestion to truncate the data at t1 and then calculate a variance to t2 is biased because it introduces a survival bias in the data (it forced the KM curve to have no event between t0 and t1). If you `plot(km2)` in your example you can easily see it. But I agree it is trivial to find the AUC between t1 and t2 as the difference of AUC(t0, t2) and AUC(t0, t1).

Comment: Interesting that you worry about a bias for the KM  curve, since it’s entirely nonparametric.  “Bias” implies some sort of “standard” of valid inference, whereas KM curves are really just descriptive.

Comment: I guess you mean print(km2, rmean = 700)

Answer (score 0):

So you know how to get an `AUC(0-t1)` and `AUC(0-t2)`. And as @missuse has pointed out in his comment, `AUC(t1-t2) = AUC(0-t2) - AUC(0-t1)`.

I am not sure if you can get a *variance* for that because technically you have one line and one area under that line (AUC). What you can do is

(**1**) plot 95%CI for Kaplan-Myer

(**2**) calculate `AUC(t1-t2)` for upper CI

(**3**) calculate `AUC(t1-t2)` for lower CI

(**4**) express the result as a range in the same way as you would express normal 95% confidence intervals.

Would that work?  And also: why do you want to use area under the KM curve? Because, as @42- pointed out, you will arrive at "life expectancy" with some time units, and you don´t need the KM to get there(?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think we can get a variance for the AUC since $\hat{S_t}$ is the realisation of a random variable.  Regarding why I want this: the AUC of a KM curve is the restricted mean survival time which is an alternative measure of treatment effect in clinical trials.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! This was exactly the reason I was interested in reason: if one could get an alternative measure for treatment effect. But what advantage AUC(KM) would offer over direct assessment of survival time in given time period?

Comment: I can see that with AUC(KM) for t1-t2 you will arrive to restricted mean survival time (RMST) but I am trying to understand the potential advantages of it..

Comment: You can find useful discussions of pros and cons of RMST in the following publications:   1. doi:10.1001/jamaoncol.2018.0518
2. doi:10.7326/M14-1741
3. 10.1200/JCO.2014.55.2208
4. doi:10.1177/1740774512455464